# Validator says it has no errors and code wont run

Tags: javascript, html

Why this code won't run, what is wrong with it? When I try to run it, it just gives me a black page, I've ran it through a HTML validator and it says it's all good. If someone can help me I'd be very grateful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title> Area of circle </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function CalculateArea(){
         
            var r = document.getElementById('form1').value;
            let p = document.getElementById('area')
            var area = (r * r * Math.PI);
            if (r%1 !=0 || r < 1) p.innerHTML = 'Please enter a whole number greater than 0';
            else p.innerHTML = area;
         }  
         <form id='form1'>
            Type radient of circle:
            <input type="text" name="txtr" size=10>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick='CalculateArea()'>
            <p id='area'></p>
         </form>
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem is in `>` or `<` in javascript in your form tag

Comment: I have sight problems but I see that your `<script>` tag is not closed, you have to close it before writing HTML (before your `<form>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## new answer

so in the `r` variables **is not** more selecting the whole form

but the only input you need (in the html I assigned a new `id` for the input)

infact in js now is selecting the input, and getting the `.value` directly from there :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Area of circle </title>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1">
        Type radient of circle:
        <input type="text" name="txtr" id="r-input" value="10">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="CalculateArea()">
        <p id="area">
        </p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript ">
        function CalculateArea() {
            var r = document.getElementById('r-input').value;
            let p = document.getElementById('area');
            var area = (r * r * Math.PI);
            if (r % 1 != 0 || r < 1) {
                p.innerHTML = 'Please enter a whole number greater than 0';
                console.log("r " + r);
                console.log("area " + area);
            } else {
                p.innerHTML = area;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

## previous answer

sometimes the ide beautify the code wrong,

not because you write wrong,

but because you insert html code in javascript... so technically the ide think that you writing js... (that the result)

### no problem, here the solution

1. copy the `<form>` code

```html
<form>

    ...

</form>
```

2. `CRTL` `X` for copy it
3. put in the start with `CTRL` `C` ( outside of `<script>` tag)
4. try to delete the spaces between the name of the tag and the `<` or `>`

### here the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Area of circle </title>
</head>

<body>

    <form id='form1'>
        Type radient of circle:
        <input type="text" name="txtr" size=1 0>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick='CalculateArea()'>
        <p id='area'>
        </p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CalculateArea() {

            var r = document.getElementById('form1').value;
            let p = document.getElementById('area')
            var area = (r * r * Math.PI);

            if (r % 1 != 0 || r < 1) {
                p.innerHTML = 'Please enter a whole number greater than 0';
            } else {
                p.innerHTML = area;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its still the same, even snippet showing the same errorits probably somewhere in this lines of code    if (r % 1 != 0 || r < 1) {
                p.innerHTML = 'Please enter a whole number greater than 0';
            } else {
                p.innerHTML = area;
            }

Comment: using console.log(); r print `undefined` @kobibrajant

Comment: thanks for help, this is not for me, ima just give up

Comment: @kobibrajant good to know, that the bug become a feature automatically #humorforprogramming

Comment: maybe this will help for me `<input type="text" name="txtr" id="r-input" size="10">` `var r = document.getElementById('r-input').value;`

Comment: i will put modified answer with the js corrected version :)

Comment: i love  you so much <3

Comment: @kobi thanks, I also put a short explanation now. appreciate that this help you :))

Answer (score 0):

The  element belongs outside the script element, in the document .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title> Area of circle </title>
   </head>
   <body>
<form id='form1'>
            Type radient of circle:
            <input type="text" name="txtr" size=10>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick='CalculateArea()'>
            <p id='area'></p>
         </form>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function CalculateArea() {
          var r = document.getElementById('form1').value;
          let p = document.getElementById('area')
          var area = (r * r * Math.PI);
          if (r%1 !=0 || r < 1) p.innerHTML = 'Please enter a whole number greater than 0';
          else p.innerHTML = area;
       }  
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: its not a blank page anymore, but i get this return on any number i type 'Please enter a whole number greater than 0';